# How to modify database schema for already running spring hibernate app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on spring project, we have data already in production, i am using annotation configuration for my entities, i have data already running, i want to add new data types and modify some already existing types, how to do that smoothly without the need to manually export the data and create import script for the new schema.

Comment: > want to add new data types ... what do you mean? Tables? Columns?

Comment: Both, new tables and new columns

Answer (score 0):

You can add tables, columns in existing tables and switch data types of some column but you should take care of these points:

- add new column: if the column is not nullable you have to either enable not null constraint after data inserts or use a default dummy value. You can remove the default clause after insertions of good values too.
- switch of type: If your db provider is capable of doing the cast directly everything is ok but if you got an error you should check at your db provider documentation if you can provide a hint for casting. For instance Postgres provides `USING` keyword for that.
  Last thing if you try change type on column serving as FK , you should drop the fk, switch type of both columns and recreate the fk.

Finally I would advice you to use a database migration tool to handle that changes. Using tool like Flyway for instance.

Comment: I am not adding new keys, only new tables and new columns, can this done pragmatically by Spring without affecting existing data?

Comment: Updated my answer... spring can do nothing for you for these use case but using a migration tool is a solution. Else you need handle that manually.